# Android room java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

What's wrong with this query? I get this at compile time:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileStagingJavaWithJavac'.
> java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
```

[image]

And that is my pojo field

[image]

Comment: Post your POJO class

Answer (score 1):

ok, so don't have perfect answer, but i can post my solution / **walkaround**.

1. You can set boolean.
2. You can get boolean.

but you can't use Boolean (in Maybe or Single)

**SOLUTION:**

1. Set in my Entity column as Boolean
2. In my Dao, i set value with boolean
3. When i want to get value i have

   `Maybe<Integer> or Single<Integer>`

In my case I use `Single<Integer>`
to later on do something like this **(it's just an example!)**

```
 public Single<Boolean> getDatabaseValue(Integer id) {
    return localDataSource
        .getDatabaseValue(id)
        .flatMap(this::toBooleanValue)  // map to Single<Boolean>
        .doOnError(throwable -> localDataSource.createFeed(id, false)) //no data, create entity
        .onErrorResumeNext(Single.just(false)); //no data, return default value
}


private Single<Boolean>toBooleanValue(Integer databaseValue) {
    return Single.just(databaseValue == 1);
}
```